# How to alter column from float(8) to numeric(64,8)

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a website that store lots of numbers in a very specific precisions (8 digits).
Most of the columns are using numeric(64,8), but I discovered that a handful are using float(8) instead, and it's causing a lot of computation issues.

How can I alter those float columns to numeric(64,8)? How do I cast the data?

Thanks!

Comment: historical note: Prior to PostgreSQL 7.4, `float(8)` used to mean 8 decimal digits; later corrected to match SQL standard measuring precision in binary digits.  8 binary is really little precision, but you don't get that, it falls into the range selecting Postgre's single-precision `real` type.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table 
   ALTER COLUMN the_float_column TYPE numeric(64,8);
```

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html

Comment: There is no need to specify any casting function using the keyword 'USING' ?

Comment: @user33563: a cast is not necessary because those two types are "compatible".